# how can I prevent a site from stealing focus in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

The site [investing.com](https://br.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl-mini-futures-historical-data) has ads and it's normal.
The problem is that even when I'm in another Chrome window, occasionally this site steals focus from that window for showing an ad and I have to go back until the next disturbing event.

PS 1: It's only this site.
PS 2: I have a antivirus.

I Googled about this issue and found nothing.

Comment: Try Adguard plugin or similar to filter ads for this site (you can enable it for specific sites only and customize what is filtered)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it...